# Cannot connect to Internet or Ethernet - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: internet, network-manager, 15.10, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my computer and I cannot connect neither with a wired nor with a wireless connection.
I also have windows on that computer and wifi works there.
I've been looking at this for hours and tried numerous suggestions but nothing worked.
I deleted and reinstalled the network manager as well, (reinstalled it by downloading the deb file on another computer and transfering it via USB)

The only connection that is available when I type

> sudo lshw -C network

is **lo** and  **enp7s0** , which I'm guessing is ethernet.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: Do you have an ip address? What does `ifconfig` tell you?